# WebView double tap zoom not working on a Motorola Droid A855

Tags: android

Zoomin in my webview will not work on a double tab. 
I am using Motorola Droid A855.

Comment: Is it working in the emulator?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly on the simulator. But not on device.

Answer (score 23):

From some digging in the Android 2.0/2.1 source code, it seems like double-taps are ignored unless you turn on the webview's WebSettings' useWideViewport option:

```
mywebviewinstance.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
```

though this appears not to be documented anywhere that I can find, and has some other effects on the max-zoomed-out state of the WebView.

You can also always roll your own double-click handling with a GestureListener, too.

Comment: This even happened on my Samsung S4 running Android 4.4.2, and in this case the documentation seems indeed poor. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Have you explicitly enabled the zoom controls? They are disabled by default.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. Double tap still not working with it (on Nexus One w/ Froyo 2.2)